Simple ODE whose solution is $r^n$ or $r^{-n}$
(Stein's Fourier Analysis, 2007 version, Exercise 11 of Chapter 1)
Consider an ODE
$$r^2F''(r)+rF'(r)-n^2F(r)=0$$
where $F(r)$ is twice differentiable when $r\gt0$.
Prove that if $n$ is a nonzero integer, then the general solution to this ODE is given by
$$F(r)=\alpha r^n+\beta r^{-n}.$$
That is, $r^n$ and $r^{-n}$ are the only (linearly independent) solutions.
My own answer following the Stein's hint.
It is enough to consider the case $n>0$ only.
First of all, we can check that $r^n$ and $r^{-n}$ satisfy the ODE.
If $n=1$, then
$$r^2(r)''+r(r)'-1^2\cdot r=0+r-r=0.$$
If $n>1$, then
$$
r^2(r^n)''+r(r^n)'-n^2\cdot r^n
=\left(n(n-1)+n-n^2\right)r^n=0.
$$
So, $r^n$ satisfies the ODE.
Moreover
$$
r^2(r^{-n})''+r(r^{-n})'-n^2\cdot r^{-n}
=\left(-n(-n-1)-n-n^2\right)r^{-n}=0.
$$
So, $r^{-n}$ also satisfies the ODE too.
Now suppose the ODE.
For $r\gt0$, let
$$g(r)=\frac{F(r)}{r^n}$$
so that $F(r)=g(r)r^n.$
Then
\begin{align*}
F'(r)&=ng(r)r^{n-1}+g'(r)r^n\\
F''(r)&=n(n-1)g(r)r^{n-2}+2ng'(r)r^{n-1}+g''(r)r^n
\end{align*}
The ODE becomes
\begin{gather*}
n(n-1)g(r)r^n + 2ng'(r)r^{n+1} + g''(r)r^{n+2} + ng(r)r^n + g'(r)r^{n+1} - n^2g(r)r^n=0\\
2ng'(r)r^{n+1} + g''(r)r^{n+2} + g'(r)r^{n+1}=0\\
2ng'(r) + g''(r)r + g'(r)=0\\
2ng'(r) + \left(rg'(r)\right)'=0\\
\frac{d}{dr}\left(2ng(r)+rg'(r)\right)=0\\
2ng(r)+rg'(r)=c
\end{gather*}
for some constant $c$.
How can I go further?
Can I solve this new ODE?
The solution to this new ODE seems to ought to be $g(r)=1$ or $g(r)=r^{-2n}$ so that $F(r)=r^n$ or $F(r)=r^{-n}$ ; $g(r)=1$ seems valid but $g(r)=r^{-2n}$ doesn't.

Why do you have to go through all this roundabout effort? Why can't you just guess the solution is of the form $Cr^m$ and solve the characteristic polynomial as is standard? There is a theorem that says an $n$th order linear ODE has exactly $n$ linearly independent solutions. The guess is also completely motivatable because monomials go down by a degree with each derivative.

Thanks for your comment. But I'm not that accustomed to general ODE theory. So I just followed the hint of the author. And actually, I don't understand your comment well. Here is my trial to understand yours. If it is not true, correct me please. If $aF''(r)+bF'(r)+cF(r)=0$, then it is a homogenous linear ODE of order 2. Its characteristic equation is $ay^2+by+c=0$. But my ODE has $a=r^2$, $b=r$ and $-n^2$. So we can take $F(r)=Cr^m$. In this procedure, what is $C$? Is it a function of $r$ or a constant?

I'm solving this considering $g(r)=y,r=x$
$$2ny+x\frac {dy}{dx}=c\\
\implies 2n\frac{y}{x}+\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac cx\\
$$
This is a (rather simplified version of) Bernoulli differential equation of the form $y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$, and so we follow the general method of solving it.  We find the $\text{"Integration factor"}$ , which is $$e^{\int p dx}=e^{\int \frac{2n}{x} dx}=e^{\ln |x^{2n}|}=x^{2n}$$
The solution is in the form
$$y(I.F)=\int Q(x) (I.F) dx + C$$
So solution will be
$$yx^{2n}=\int \frac cx x^{2n} dx + C=\frac{cx^{2n}}{2n} + C$$
This can be further simplified to
$$\frac{F(r)}{r^n} r^{2n}=\frac{cr^{2n}}{2n}+C\\
\implies F(r)=\frac{c}{2n} r^n + Cr^{-n}  $$
Note
Originally, Bernoulli equations are of the form $y'+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n$, for which $I.F=e^{(1-n)\int P(x) dx}$, and solution is of the form
$$y(I.F)=(1-n)\int Q(x) (I.F) dx+ C$$

Sorry for my late comment and thanks for your nice explanation. I think I learned the integrating factor when I was undergraduate, but I forgot it all. Now I know the general way to solve it as you guided and this can also be applied to my case. (Maybe one can say there are more general form of ODE and solutions). Thanks!

This equation type is called "Euler-Cauchy" (or "Cauchy-Euler"). The standard solution procedure was explained in the comments.
No, you can not show that this is the only basis, any two linear combinations of this, if they are linearly independent, give another basis. One can say that this is the only monomial basis.
Using differential operators, one can factorize
$$
0=(r^2D^2+rD-n^2)F=((rD)^2-n^2)=(rD+n)(rD-n)F.
$$
Thus one can split into a first-order system
$$
(rD-n)F=G,\\
(rD+n)G=0,
$$
and solve these first-order linear equations backwards
